# Machine learning fall detection using time-series analysis

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, time-series

I'm trying to train a classifier to detect a fall based on accelerometer and gyroscope data. However, I'm having a hard time determining what type of algorithm to use. 
This is a picture of some of the dataset:[image: Accelerometer training data]

This data is an example of raw x-,y- and z-coordinates read from the accelerometer during a fall. As you can see, the data is relatively steady until the point where the fall begins. 

My question is: what classifier should I use to detect the fall. 
 
I've read some research in the field, where the scientists used Naive-Bayes algorithms to classify the data, but as I understand it, Naive-Bayes doesn't take into account the previous datasets in the classification. 
I thought about using an HMM, but since I'm quite new to machine learning, I thought I'd ask for some general guidance. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [Conditional Random Field (CRF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field) which can be used as a classifier to take "neighboring samples" into account. If you do some google search, you should be able to find some papers about "fall detection" with CRF.

As you mentioned, HMM is also an appropriate model for your problem, in which you have a hidden variable (fall or not) but unobservable (only x-y-z coordinates are observable).

Comment: This was exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Thanks!